# Checking user availability in registration form. Already an AJAX request is present in the current html file. How can i add another one?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hey guys i've done a registration where the user registers himself and after submitting the data gets stored automatically. Already in the present html file, i've given an ajax request and the operation for register.php. Now i would like to implement a criteria of "Checking the user availability". Here is where i'm confused. If i give this ajax request, then how will i be able to do the register.php? Please help me out. Thanks.

```
<body>
<div class="app-block">
        <div class="cube"><img src="images/cube.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></div>
        <form method="post">
<div id="reg-data"></div>
<input type="text" name="username" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name" id="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Enter your password" id="password" />

<input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Please give your location" id="location" />
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Where do you work?" id="company" />
<input type="text" name="designation" placeholder="Provide your designation" id="designation" />
<label for="gender">Gender </label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required" id="gender" value="Male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required" id="gender" value="Female"/>Female
<br/><br/>
<label for="qualification">Qualification</label>
<select name="qualification" value="Qualification" id="qualification">
<option value="SSLC">SSLC</option>
<option value="HSC">HSC</option>
<option value="UG">UG</option>
<option value="PG">PG</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Cricket" />Cricket
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Music" />Music
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Swimming" />Swimming
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"  id="reg" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
<p class="sign">Already Registered? <a href="lo.php"> Login</a></p>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#reg').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var username = $("#username").val();
 if( username == '') {
    alert('Enter the username');
    header('location: register.html');
 } else {
 var password = $("#password").val();
 if( password == '') {
    alert('Enter the password');
    header('location: register.html');
 } else {
 var gender = $("#gender").val();
 var qualification = $("#qualification").val();
 var hobbies = $("#hobbies").val();
 var location = $("#location").val();
 var company = $("#company").val();
 var designation = $("#designation").val();
 }}
 $.ajax({
    url: "register.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "username="+username+"& password="+password+"& gender="+gender+"& qualification="+qualification+"& hobbies="+hobbies+"& location="+location+"& company="+company+"& designation="+designation,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#reg-data').html(data);
        $('#username').val('');
        $('#password').val('');
        $('#gender').val('');
        $('#qualification').val('');
        $('#hobbies').val('');
        $('#location').val('');
        $('#company').val('');
        $('#designation').val('');

     },

     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message); }
});
});

});
</script>
</body>
```

Now i've another ajax request, but confused of where to put that.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#username').keyup(check_username);
});
function check_username(){
 var username = $('#username').val();
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_username.php',
        data: 'username='+ username,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 0){
               alert('Username available')
            }
            else {
                 alert('Username not available')

            }
         }
     });
}
</script>
```

Comment: remove  header('location: ')  it is not the js..

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it one after another

there is no harm in concecutive Ajax request in one file

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // for user registration 
     $('#reg').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var username = $("#username").val();
     if( username == '') {
        alert('Enter the username');
        header('location: register.html');
     } else {
     var password = $("#password").val();
     if( password == '') {
        alert('Enter the password');
        header('location: register.html');
     } else {
     var gender = $("#gender").val();
     var qualification = $("#qualification").val();
     var hobbies = $("#hobbies").val();
     var location = $("#location").val();
     var company = $("#company").val();
     var designation = $("#designation").val();
     }}
       $.ajax({
          url: "register.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: "username="+username+"& password="+password+"& gender="+gender+"& qualification="+qualification+"& hobbies="+hobbies+"& location="+location+"& company="+company+"& designation="+designation,
          success: function(data, status, xhr) {
              $('#reg-data').html(data);
              $('#username').val('');
              $('#password').val('');
              $('#gender').val('');
              $('#qualification').val('');
              $('#hobbies').val('');
              $('#location').val('');
              $('#company').val('');
              $('#designation').val('');

           },

           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message); }
      });
    });
    // check username 

    $('#username').keyup(function(){
        var username = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check_username.php',
                data: 'username='+ username,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == 0){
                       alert('Username available')
                    }
                    else {
                         alert('Username not available')

                    }
                 }
             });
    });

});


 </script>
```

### OR

Create a file **registration.js** and paste the whole code in it without `script` tag and include it in your file

```
  <script src='path/to/registration.js'></script>
```

Comment: No man. It's not working. I have tried every other way. Have any clue of what can be done?

Comment: No error at all. When I type a single letter itself alert is popping up saying 'Username not available'. And even if i enter an existing username and password it is being registered

Answer (score 0):

try with this...

```
function check_username(){
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_username.php',
        data: 'username='+ $('#username').val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            return response;
         }
     });
}
```

and in validation

```
var successStatus = check_username();
if(successStatus != 1){
  alert('username already Exist');
  return false;
 }
```